# How to move a heading inline?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup, typography

I want to emulate this design of having "titles" on paragraphs in HTML/CSS.

[image: Screenshot where there is a bold "title" at the beginning of a paragraph]

Semantically, these "titles" should be headings. Is there a way to achieve this for paragraphs and list-items in CSS? My best idea is to declare the paragraph/list-item after such a heading to display in-line, but that creates weird spacing issues: because I'm declaring a paragraph after a heading to display inline and the *not* clear the heading, if the previous paragraph is short it will move to merge with that previous paragraph. And for list-items, the inter-item spacing (margin) is no longer respected.

```css
h4 {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}

h4::after {
  content: "\2006\00B7\2006";
}

h4+p,
h4+li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

p,
ul,
li {
  clear: both;
  margin: 2em 0 2em 0;
}
```

```html
<h4> Paragraph Heading </h4>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
<h4> The Next Paragraph Heading </h4>
<p> Because the last paragraph was too short, this gets moved up; bummer. </p>
<p> Maecenas hendrerit nibh auctor odio interdum, eget dictum felis pulvinar. Nulla mollis sem convallis lorem aliquet scelerisque. Vestibulum auctor ac metus nec varius. Cras sed tortor pharetra, ullamcorper tortor non, euismod turpis. Sed quis scelerisque
  ante, gravida finibus massa. Integer elementum eget sapien ac iaculis. Cras tincidunt auctor lacus, rhoncus mattis metus tincidunt sed. Phasellus molestie nunc sit amet sapien viverra iaculis. Aenean aliquam felis sed blandit mattis. Donec imperdiet
  turpis nisi, ut tincidunt dolor congue a. </p>
<ul>
  <h4> List-Item Heading </h4>
  <li> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam cursus rutrum risus quis sollicitudin. Aenean pharetra, orci ac euismod bibendum, nibh dolor vehicula lorem, vitae rhoncus lectus tellus id ante. Nullam quis magna finibus, pharetra turpis
    eu, lobortis risus. Cras semper placerat nisl, id consequat metus sodales eget. Etiam tincidunt justo consectetur tristique egestas. Ut sed venenatis elit. Sed ligula lacus, molestie maximus nisl eget, auctor interdum velit. Etiam condimentum faucibus
    viverra. Curabitur interdum sem arcu, quis iaculis magna sodales at. Proin tristique viverra tortor dictum convallis. </li>
  <h4> List-Item Heading </h4>
  <li> The list-item spacing is wonky here.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The question is worded as if you were seeking opinions (which is off-topic for SO) - however, are you trying to figure out the _weird spacing issues_ with your approach? If so, can you describe what you mean by this?

Comment: I think I'd like to know if it's possible to emulate what's in the screenshot without replacing the `<h4>` with a general `<div>` for the sake of accessibility. I'll add details of the spacing issue in the post.

Comment: I'd remove the opinion-seeking language in the title and the question ("should be headings, right?", "Is there a proper way"). Assume that you are correct and make the question about how to achieve the effect, rather than on the squishy stuff like whether it's semantically correct or not.

Comment: IIRC, only `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>` elements are allowed inside `<ul>` tags so your markup is not valid right now.

Comment: @blurfus I kinda suspected. This means there's no *valid* way to stick those headings on list items.

Comment: `<li><h4>Header</h4> Text</li>` is valid...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Oh okay! But a header inside a paragraph is not valid (right?) so I'd have to break up the CSS for these cases

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'll think about how to edit the post (I hope you feel free to edit it to make a better SO post too). But yeah I was trying to avoid the post sounding like "How do you do this in HTML/CSS without divs?" to keep it useful/findable to future users

Comment: Correct! a heading inside a paragraph is not valid (semantically) either because, well, it's supposed to be a paragraph and contain text within (and a few other elements known as phrasing content) - A heading _can_ be styled to look like above, I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of the way there just by making `h4` and `p` have `display: inline;`, removing the margin on `h4`, and adding a block-level non-breaking space after the paragraph.

`li` elements take care of themselves once you move the `h4` element within them.

```css
p::after {
  content: "\00A0";
  display: block;
}
h4, p {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}
h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0;
}
h4::after {
  content: "\2006\00B7\2006";
}
```

```html
<h4> Paragraph Heading </h4>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
<h4> The Next Paragraph Heading </h4>
<p> Because the last paragraph was too short, this gets moved up; bummer. </p>
<p> Maecenas hendrerit nibh auctor odio interdum, eget dictum felis pulvinar. Nulla mollis sem convallis lorem aliquet scelerisque. Vestibulum auctor ac metus nec varius. Cras sed tortor pharetra, ullamcorper tortor non, euismod turpis. Sed quis scelerisque
  ante, gravida finibus massa. Integer elementum eget sapien ac iaculis. Cras tincidunt auctor lacus, rhoncus mattis metus tincidunt sed. Phasellus molestie nunc sit amet sapien viverra iaculis. Aenean aliquam felis sed blandit mattis. Donec imperdiet
  turpis nisi, ut tincidunt dolor congue a. </p>
<ul>
  <li> <h4> List-Item Heading </h4> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam cursus rutrum risus quis sollicitudin. Aenean pharetra, orci ac euismod bibendum, nibh dolor vehicula lorem, vitae rhoncus lectus tellus id ante. Nullam quis magna finibus, pharetra turpis
    eu, lobortis risus. Cras semper placerat nisl, id consequat metus sodales eget. Etiam tincidunt justo consectetur tristique egestas. Ut sed venenatis elit. Sed ligula lacus, molestie maximus nisl eget, auctor interdum velit. Etiam condimentum faucibus
    viverra. Curabitur interdum sem arcu, quis iaculis magna sodales at. Proin tristique viverra tortor dictum convallis. </li>
  <li><h4> List-Item Heading </h4> The list-item spacing is wonky here.</li>
</ul>
```